# How to scale and modify the position of ImageButton dynamically?

Tags: android, android-widget, imagebutton

I create an ImageButton on main.xml.
And I want to scale the size and modify the position of ImageButton on the View.

main.xml

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/BtnExplore" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/btn_320x240_explorer"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
/>
```

I will set the size - iwidth and iheight when user click the button - Next and Prev.

Next button pressed.

```
                iHeight++;
                iWidth++;
                BtnExplore.setMaxHeight(iHeight);
                BtnExplore.setMaxWidth(iWidth);
                BtnExplore.invalidate();
                BtnExplore.postInvalidate();
```

Prev button pressed.

```
                iHeight--;
                iWidth--;
                BtnExplore.setMaxHeight(iHeight);
                BtnExplore.setMaxWidth(iWidth);
                BtnExplore.invalidate();
```

I still can't scale the imagebutton.
I also need how to change the position.

Here is the complete code.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2452511/AndroidAP/IconClickTest-stackoverflow.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Use `setMinimumHeight` and `setMinimumWidth`

Comment: It is not workable after I test. I am not sure where the problem is. Is something wrong with setMinimumHeight or invalidate function?